# Why can't I create a Google Analytics property view?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to use Google Analytics as a data stream for Google Data Studio but it requires me to have a property view. There is no option for me to create a view in my property in the administration page:

[image]

There is no column named Views:

[image]

Is there something I need to do to be able to create new views?

OBS.: My Google Analytics account was imported directly from Firebase.

Answer (score 14):

Google Analytics is changing and it is a bit confusing. I will try to clarify it for you. As far as I have gone, evolution has been:

1.- "App + web property" (Beta phase)

2.- "Universal Analytics" (*) (until 14-Oct-2020): It is identified because the account number is preceded by "UA-" eg. UA-123456789 (Attention, sometimes it is not very obvious and you have to create a new user to see the UA prefix). This option is only suitable for the monitoring and analysis of Web pages and has the option of analysis using "Views" enabled. If you don't have it, you should:

```
2.a.- Create a new "Property"
2.b.- "Show advanced options"
2.c.- Activate "Create an Analytics Property"
2.d.- Create only one "Universal Analytics" Property
```

3.- "Google Analytics 4": It is identified because the account number is preceded by "GA4-" eg. GA4-123456789. In this case, the analysis is not done through "View" but through "Data Stream" (** incorporating a series of improvements) although Google offers the possibility of creating two "Properties" one in UA format with Views and another in GA4 format with Data Stream

In all cases, you must place the corresponding gtag provided by Google Analytics within the  tag of the page you want to analyze.

Sources

(*) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=es&utm_id=ad

(**) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061?hl=es&utm_id=ad

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9367631

Answer (score 0):

[https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9539598?hl=en#:~:text=If%20you%20set%20up%20a,with%20%22UA%2D%22](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9539598?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20you%20set%20up%20a,with%20%22UA%2D%22)).

This is a good answer to that question. I had the same problem. In case the URL doesn't load, essentially,...

"If you set up a Google Analytics 4 property with a Web data stream, you have a Measurement ID (which begins with "G-").
If you set up a Universal Analytics ("Web") property (Universal Analytics properties have views instead of data streams), you have a Tracking ID (which begins with "UA-")."

You cannot have the property be a Google Analytics 4 property with a web data stream and have a view page as well. If you want the View page, then when you create the property, make sure its Universal Analytics.

Hope this helps, I'm new to this game.